# returning the best element from the list L according to function F?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

i am trying to write a function in lisp which have 2 parameters one function F and one list L
if i place '> in place of F and list L is '(1 2 3 4 5) it will return 5 as 5 is biggest.
and if we put '< then it compares all list elements and gives the smallest one as output.
and so on.

we can even put custom written function in place of F for comparison.
i wish i could provide more sample code but i am really stuck at the start.

```
(DEFUN givex (F L)
(cond
    (F (car L) (car (cdr L))
    ;after this i got stuck  
)
)
```

another attemp to write this function

```
(defun best(F list)
    (if (null (rest list)) (first list)
    (funcall F (first List) (best (F list)))))
```

Comment: This assumes that the elements of the list under relation `F` form a totally ordered set, which isn't always the case. For example, a list of `(0.0 -1.0 1.0 +nan+)` under relation `<` will not produce consistent results because both `(< 0.0 +nan+)` and `(< +nan+ 0.0)` are false. To add to this argument: 1) you don't want to use lists for this task because it is suited for sets, which disallow repetition. 2) assuming and the total order can be established, sorting will give you the desired result.

Comment: @wvxvw: sorting is linearithmic, max search is linear.

Comment: @sds only if the set operation is binary. If it is defined on more then two elements it is no longer linear and in the worst case quadratic.

Comment: @wvxvw: you lost me, sorry. In this problem `f` is a function of 2 arguments. What setting ("set operation") are you talking about?

Comment: @sds I was talking about [finitary relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation), I didn't know that's what it's called (learned math in different language).

Comment: @wvxvw: how is this relevant to this question or my comment? what does sorting have to do with it?

Comment: @sds `max` is a binary relation, or you can reduce it to be binary, but some relations cannot be reduced to that, so if following the Wikipedia example you wanted to find a person who was introduced to most persons in the group, you'd need a ternary relation (and thus not being able to user `reduce` for example). You wouldn't be able to use `sort` library function, but in general the operation of finding the "most introduced" person would amount to sorting. Umm... now I'm not sure it'd be sorting. Wait :)

Comment: @sds OK, I admit that I don't know actually, and it pains to think of what the appropriate procedure would be :) Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, just the else clause returns the `f`'s return value instead of the the `best` element:

```
(defun best (F list)
  (let ((first (first list))
        (rest (rest list)))
    (if (null rest)
        first
        (let ((best (best f rest)))
          (if (funcall F first best)
              best
              first)))))
```

Examples:

```
(best #'< '(1 2 3))
==> 3
(best #'> '(1 2 3))
==> 1
```

Note that this recursive implementation is not tail-recursive, so it is not the most efficient one. You might prefer this instead:

```
(defun best (f list) 
  (reduce (lambda (a b) (if (funcall f a b) b a)) list))
```

Or, better yet,

```
(defmacro fmax (f)
  `(lambda (a b) (if (,f a b) b a)))

(reduce (fmax <) '(1 2 3))
==> 1
(reduce (fmax >) '(1 -2 3 -4) :key #'abs)
==> 1
(reduce (fmax <) '(1 -2 3 -4) :key #'abs)
==> 4
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I was looking for an answer using `reduce` and now I don't have to write it. Excellent!

Comment: @Vatine: note that you get `:key` handling for free with `reduce`!

Comment: It's interesting to think about `<` and `max`, here.  The anonymous function `(lambda (a b) (if (funcall f a b) b a))` is to `<` what `max` is to `<`.  I point this out because `(reduce 'max list)` is much more concise than `(reduce (lambda (a b) (if (funcall '< a b) b a)) list)`.  I'd also suggest that the OP write, e.g., an `fmax` function `(defun fmax (a b) (if (f a b) b a))` so that OP can do `(reduce 'fmax list)`.